# How to Upload File along with some complex type in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api, complextype

I have a requirement, where I have to upload file using WEB API. So created a api controller for Post and handled the Multi-part form data and I could successfully upload the files. But I need to pass an complex type with properties such as  FileName, Description, FormId, etc... along with the file. So how to achieve this using single Post Controller. For eg.)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] MyComplexType myType)
{
    //Here I get the files from Request.Content.ReadAsAsyncStream();
    // myType is always null. 
}
```

Also from Client Side (Javascript and .NET Client) I can post either Mutlipart Formdata or the Complex type. But I need to do both in same request.

Please help....

Comment: Have you got the answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into using `MultipartFormDataProvider` where the request is a multipart request having 'formurlencoded' data + files?...but if your request is like 'json' data + files, then you can use `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`...if files are huge and memory usage is a concern, you can create a custom `MultipartStreamProvider`...